# How to find Amazon RedShift Service Provider in Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-redshift

I'm looking for Amazon RedShift Service Provider. Despite myinvestigations, I only find provider Amazon S3 Bucket. How can find service provider and user's guide.

Comment: if Service Provider is a way to connect to the DB and run queries you can use some standard SQL provider or Postgres provider

Comment: @AlexYes really!! Thx for answer :)))

Answer (score 0):

if Service Provider is a way to connect to the DB and run queries you can use some standard SQL provider or Postgres provider